# AEM SideKick || Comparing the two versions of page in AEM from content authoring view

Tags: java, aem

I am trying to compare the two versions of the same page with "diff" functionality but differences are not reflecting.

**Steps I have followed:**
1) I have created 1.0 version of the page and the did some changes.
2) in sidekick we checked the diff with the version we created earlier. but our changes were still same for both versions.

---

Hi,
- I have an open one page and created a version "first". where 1.0 was already created before.
- then I have removed the "A" from one content and tried to check with "diff" in another tab. but "A" was not present in both the versions nor any highlighted space as per adobe docs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when i try to reproduce the issue. the only difference i can see is in your sidekick there are no versions available. *please provide some more steps in detail.*

**steps for general any version creation and comparison**.

1. create a version for the page from side kick.
2. change any content in the page.
3. Go to version tab in sidekick, expand the restore version.
4. Enable check box on any version which you want to compare.
5. Click on the Diff button to see the result.

*More over observed that it shows only the differences in text content not the components that has been added which has some static content in its jsps*
[image]

Comment: Please check the post.
I have edited that and added some more things.

Comment: Can you please check about this?